# text field input color css

Tags: javascript, css

I have a text filed in my form. The color of the text in the text field should be in grey color. If i click it and type, the text should turn black and remains to be in black color.

I used the following css.

```
input[type=text]{ color:#999999;}
input[type=text]:focus{ color:#000;}
```

This is my html code

```
<input name="address" id="address" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value =='Address' ) this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Address'" value="Address">
```

Now the text turns to black color when i am typing. But it turns back to grey color after typing. I need it to be in black after typing. How can i do that?

Comment: so you mean you dont want to change the color of your text when typing and after typing right?

Comment: Why can't you use the `placeholder` attribute for the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
<input name="address" id="address" type="text" 
       onFocus="if(this.value =='Address' )this.value='';this.style.color='#000';" 
       onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Address'; if (this.value=='Address') this.style.color='#999';" 
       value="Address">
```

Comment: Hi, one more help. If i click the reset button the input text should turn to grey again. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your question is 100% clear but why don't you just reverse the values in your CSS?

```
<style>
input[type=text]{ color:#000;}
input[type=text]:focus{ color:#999999;}
</style>

<p>
<input name="address" id="address" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value =='Address' ) this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Address'" value="Address">
</p>
```

With this the text is black and on focus it's gray but after focus it goes back to black.

Answer (score 0):

I have used JQuery to solve your problem. Please have a look at this JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/EvnQj/

Answer (score 0):

For Above issue, please write HTML as below:

```
<input name="address" id="address" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value =='Address' ) this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value==''){ this.value='Address'; } else{ this.style.color='#000'; }" value="Address">
```

CSS as it is:

```
input[type=text]{
  color:#999999;
}
input[type=text]:focus{
  color:#000;
}
```

and if you want to test your bin then http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpaq